# True/False right angle function in python

Tags: python, function, geometry

I can't seem to get my function to work. When I type in 3 for a, 2 for b, and 3.61 for c. That works. However, when I try those values in a different order (Ex: 3.61 for a, 3 for b and 2 for c) It returns as false. I can't figure out what the problem is. Thanks in advance!

```
a = input("Enter a ")
b = input("Enter b ")
c = input("Enter c ")


def isright_angled():
    if abs((a**2+b**2)-(c**2)) < 0.1 or abs((c**2-a**2)-(b**2)) < 0.1 or abs((c**2-b**2)-(a**2)) < 0.1:                         
        return True
    else:
        return False

print isright_angled()
```

Comment: Why do you sum the first two squares in the first block, and subtract them in the others? Your algo isn't symmetric wrt a/b/c.

Comment: use [raw_input](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=input#raw_input) instead. `input` is not what you want...

Comment: It's to find each of the variables from the hypotenuse equation.
Also my function doesn't work when there is raw_input.

Comment: use `raw_input([prompt])` like `my_float = float(raw_input("Enter a float"))`

Comment: @Fredrik Not true in Python 3 (although he still has to cast the input). It seems like we're checking whether a^2+b^2==c^2 holds (with c being the hypothenuse) in an extremely round about manner. Just check which side is the largest.

Comment: @Voo OP is using python 2.x given his using print isright_angled() rather than print(isright_angled())

Comment: @Chad Oh you're right sorry. I'm always using the new print function even in python2 code so I didn't even think of looking for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hypotenuse, if the triangle is right-angled, will be the largest of a, b and c. You can use that to avoid duplicating the test 3 times (this is the "don't repeat yourself" principle). A second thing to avoid is that `if something: return True else: return False`. It's usually better expressed as simply `return something`. Thirdly, functions can take arguments rather than relying on global variables: this makes things easier to understand and there's then less chance of functions interfering with each other. I find `a * a` easier to understand than `a ** 2` but that's personal taste. Putting all that together:

```
def is_approximately_right_angled(a, b, c):
    a, b, c = sorted([a, b, c])
    return abs(a * a + b * b - c * c) < 0.1

a = input('enter a ')
b = input('enter b ')
c = input('enter c ')
print is_approximately_right_angled(a, b, c)
```

If it's not working, you can speed up your development by adding some checks. If you were writing a big program you can write unit tests, but here just some asserts in the module will avoid you having to type a, b, c in each time to test.

I'd add something like this (before the `a = input...` line):

```
assert is_approximately_right_angled(3, 4, 5)
assert is_approximately_right_angled(3, 5, 4)
assert is_approximately_right_angled(3, 2, 3.61)
assert not is_approximately_right_angled(3, 5, 5)
```

With these lines in place, you can have some confidence in the code before you get to type numbers in. When you find cases where the code doesn't work you can add them as additional checks.

Comment: Instead of just using an "approximately right-angled" test, you could use the cosine law to actually determine the angle opposite the hypotenuse.

Comment: @Karl floating point arithmetic is by its nature approximate. Try `.03 * .03 + .04 * .04 == .05 * .05`: this should be True, but because of inaccuracy it's actually False. Using trig won't help with these sorts of accuracy problems.

Comment: @PaulHankin Of course I am aware of how floating-point works. My argument is that returning an angle value, and letting the calling code decide if it's close enough to 90 degrees, is far more robust than hard-coding a threshold value for the Pythagorean check (a value which isn't even scaled according to the input).

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input("Enter the side length" ))
b = int(input("Enter the side length" ))
c = int(input("Enter the side length" ))

def is_right_triangle(a,b,c):
    '''
    is_right_triangle(a,b,c) -> bool
    returns True if a,b,c is a right triangle with hypotenuse c
    '''
    a, b, c = sorted([a, b, c])
    return a*a + b*b == c*c

print(is_right_triangle(a,b,c))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your desire to answer questions posted by others is very welcome here, but please take a closer look at the questions before posting a new answer: this question here was asked more than 9 years ago (you can see the time when question was asked right below the question above the question's author avatar picture). More importantly - this question already has a clear accepted answer. Usually you want to post new answers only if there are no existing ones or if your answer contains something new compared to existing answers.

Answer (score -1):

for more accuracy you can use
return abs(a * a + b * b  - c * c) < 0.001